# Railway Springboot app not connecting from other networks/ locations,

Tags: java, android, spring-boot, backend, railway

I deployed a Springboot app and MySQL database on Railway.app.
It works as intended on my android emulator and personal device. I sent it to a friend somewhere else within the country to test it and it isn't working for him.
I checked the logs and the server isn't receiving the request at all. But his network connection is fine.
What could be the problem?

I have tested the app again on my end and it works.